# Can't access to variable inside a function arguments call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability-helper

```
case 'ADD_CHAT_MESSAGE':
    const index = state.tasks.findIndex(elm => elm.userid === action.taskid)
    const task = state.tasks
    return update(
      state, { tasks: { index: { $set: action.task } } })
```

I would like to use index inside `update` function but  my IDE alerting me that `index` is declared nut never used.

Answer (score 2):

Since index is dynamic, you must use `[]` with it, otherwise it will just be setting the `index` key

```
case 'ADD_CHAT_MESSAGE':
    const index = state.tasks.findIndex(elm => elm.userid === action.taskid)
    const task = state.tasks
    return update(
      state, { tasks: { [index]: { $set: action.task } } })
```